# my jsf application firstly goes to localhost

Tags: jsf

I have asked a question  my jsf web application before.

Then I realized that it firstly goes to localhost and in second trial its
 address www.deprem.gov.tr:8080/pro1/bir.jsf

it runs

Could tell me what the reasons might be in first attempt it goes to localhost and in second trial it runs when I entered the address.

kind reg

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some redirect in your code, there is no reason for a jsf (or any web app) to get redirected to localhost.

You can debug this by putting a breakpoint on the `response.sendRedirect(..)` method and inspect the stack.